# Error during npm install

Tags: node.js, npm-install

Whenever I run npm install , I get error "**unable to access 'http://ikt.pm2.io/ikt.git/': Failed to connect to ikt.pm2.io port 80: Timed
 out**"

For example when I run command **npm install jest** it get stucked for some time and then throw above error. I tried running npm install from Windows Console,Git Bash and VS Code terminal without any success.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall or something?

Comment: @JeremyThille : Yes, but I have set proxy setting in npmrc

Comment: Did you try `npm config set proxy http://user:password@proxy.com:port` and `npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@proxy.com:port` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille : It was proxy issue but for git not for npm , needed to set proxy settings for Git, I have posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle, I found that there was issue with my Git config settings, there need's to be proxy property in your git config if your behind proxy. Once I added the proxy setting it worked fine

You can check git config settings using command

```
git config -l
```

if proxy setting are not present add it using

```
git config --global http.https-proxy <your proxy>
```